# Gridview with button and text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android I want to ask help how can achieve design like this that have 4 buttons ,icons and text. and it has icon in header part.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, thank you I will try, what about the icon on top ?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: You can change position . At first check How it works

Comment: This design looks like iOS design. I hate when somebody is trying to make iOSy design in Android, looks ugly . But anyway look here https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started it could help you. If you don't like GridView and the Adapter attached to it, you can use LinearLayout to construct your views.

Comment: @sniper I don't have idea if that is ios design i thought it was android design

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html

Comment: About the gridview I am fine, but the toolbar design is nothing else then iOS, Change the toolbar design and then it will be fine :). Goodluck

Comment: ok I heard about material design is this also can be applied ?

Comment: how to make the icon look that size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:Decide which layout should u use.I think u can use Gridlayout of 2*2.Or you can just use linearlayout and set weight.
Second:In gridlayout you can use button or Imageview or TextView(drawableTop).

Answer (score 1):

Yes You Can

You can use many options [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), CardView Or LinearLayout
, and for the icon header you Can Customize the Toolbar as described in the developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

for your images in the in the above screenshot which you have provided you can use [Image Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) in android and you can set their size according to you and for the header you can use any layout of your choice.
Thank you