# Resizing Icon in Textview with text Icon not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a problem in resizing the image in my **TextView**. It will not display the icon. I want my icon size to be like this and with text [icon with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235609/gridview-with-button-and-text) I don't know what is the problem of my code why it will not display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mytxview1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/button1_style"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon1_48dp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:text = "Button 1"


        />


        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:background="@drawable/button2_style"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon2_48dp"
                android:tint="#ffffff"
                android:text = "Button 2"

                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon3_48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button3_style"
                android:tint="#ffffff"
                android:text = "Button 3"
              />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon4_48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button4_style"
                android:text = "Button 4"
               />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is how I resize:

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytxview1);
    Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.button_style);
    icon.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
    txt1.setCompoundDrawables(icon,null,null,null);
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can try ``Button`` with ``drawable`` inside?

Comment: button then android:drawableTop ?

Comment: yes you can try

Comment: is my java code is correct no changes on that ?

Comment: I dont know...i did not test it...sorry

Comment: not working... the problem i can show text and image but the image i cannot resize

Comment: you can use linear layout with imagview and textview.

Comment: @AkashPatel he wants to combine in one element

Comment: @DonaldWu not necessarily , I just want to come out the looks design  in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235609/gridview-with-button-and-text..

Comment: @AkashPatel, can you show me please how...

Comment: Ddi you try to use ``drawablePadding`` to resize? or use width and height?

Comment: What button style you have used for each textViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/toolElvation">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/action_home"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_18"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.36"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.495"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_with_grayborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_warranty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
            android:text="@string/my_warranty"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.495"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_with_grayborder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_warranty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
            android:text="@string/my_warranty"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_5dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.36"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.495"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_with_grayborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_warranty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
            android:text="@string/my_warranty"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.495"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_with_grayborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_warranty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
            android:text="@string/my_warranty"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.26"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lntltProductUse"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/my_warranty" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
                android:text="@string/my_warranty"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_1dp"
            android:text="@string/my_warranty"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_14"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**bg_with_grayborder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dip"
    android:radius="20dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dip"
    android:topRightRadius="20dip" />

<stroke
    android:color="@color/sub_text"
    android:width="1dip" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

You could use your color in `<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />`.

Comment: can I use my buttonstyle ?

Comment: @jemz What is your button style? and also check my edit.

Comment: where I can get those @dimen/toolElvation ?

Comment: @jemz In **dimens.xml** file or you can set directly like **5dp** etc.

Comment: @Akask Patel, thank you ...how can I make my icon bigger in imageview android:layout_width ?

Comment: @jemz increase your image size as per your requirement or set height and width of imageview.

Comment: Thank you for helping me